# Вывести наименьшее время доставки всех подарков

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Вот условие задачи.
Входные данные:
В первой строке находится количество подарков n (1 ≤ n ≤ 300). В следующих двух строках содержится по n чисел, соответственно: во второй строке – время упаковки каждого подарка, а в третьей – время его доставки. Известно, что 0 < t1, t2 ≤ 1000.

Выходные данные:
Вывести наименьшее время доставки всех подарков.

Не могу понять как определить сколько еще нужно прибавить подарков к суме и стоит ли это делать?

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, t1, t2;

    cin >> n;
    int s1 = 0;
    int s2 = 0;

    int ts[n];
    int td[n];
    int mn = td[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> t1;
        s1 += t1;
        ts[i] = t1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> t2;
        s2 += t2;
        td[i] = t2;
        if (td[i] < mn) {
            mn = td[i];
        }

    }

    if (s1 == s2 || s1 < s2) {
        cout << s2;
    } else if (s1 > s2) {
        cout << s1 + mn;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://site.ada.edu.az/~medv/acm/Docs%20e-olimp/Volume%201/26.htm